# In UltraEdit for Mac, I want to replace group0(full match) with group0 plus some more

Tags: regex, perl, pcre, ultraedit

I'm using UltraEdit in Perl regex mode to do that.
i.e. `(cat) (dog)` replaced with `$0\n$1 $2`

Although the $1 and $2 worked, I couldn't find a way to make `$0` work.

Does anyone experience this issue?

Comment: If `$0` doesn't work then group the whole pattern and then use `$1` for whole match

Comment: Thanks @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I was thinking about that solution, but was really curious why `$0` doesn't work on UltraEdit, I've tried `$0` on Sublime Text, and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, in some regex dialects `$0` works like in Java also it works but in some other dialects it doesn't work, as it seems just not supported, hence that's the obvious and easy workaround.

Comment: I'll go with that method if couldn't find another way. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using "Perl" regular expressions in Ultra Edit,

- `$&` contains the matched text.
- `` $` `` contains the portion of the document leading up to the matched text.
- `$'` contains the portion of the document following the matched text.

This is documented [here](https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/perl-regular-expressions.html). (Scroll down to "Perl regex output modifiers".)

This is consistent with Perl, where `$0` contains the first argument to the program (the name of the program).

[image: Screenshot of Demonstration]